# Transfer data between wpf forms

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, forms

I have build a wpf form that launches a new form . The new form fetches some more data . Now i want the data to be reflected back into the main form i.e implement the "SAVE" button on the popped up form . My data to be saved is in the form of ObservableCollection List . I am not sure how i do this .

Breakdown of Steps

Step 1 : Main form launches

Step 2 : Click on main from to launch  form 2.

Step 3 : Fetch data from database populate form 2 . The user selects a few values here .

step 4 : Click on "Save" button in form 2 so that values are refelected in Main Form .

i am done with steps 1-3 . I am quite unsure how do so step 4 . I cannot do databinding here since the list is defined in form 2 ( or is there a way out ? ) Do i now need to save data in the database and then do a query ?

Comment: The *quick and dirty but working way*: pass the reference to the form1 instance in the form2 constructor.

Comment: @SteveB thanks for the idea i was able to do it with your suggestion . Many thanks .

Answer (score 1):

Create ObservableCollection variable in MainForm and assign initial null value. Pass this variable to the form 2. If user press Save button, create an instance of these variable and add values to these variables in form 2. If user press cancel button set this variable to null. In MainForm after form 2 open/close code, check if variable is not null, then some value has been assigned to these variable in form 2. So use that variable further.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue by making use of Steves suggestions posted in the comments . The way to do it is to "pass the reference of the mainform to the second form in the constructor"

Example :

MainForm :

```
public void updateText(String data)
{
    txb.Text = data;
}
```

Form 2 :

```
// Here the constructor takes a reference of the Mainform . 
MainWindow mainform = null;

public Form2(MainWindow w)
{
    mainform = w;
    ......
}
// Perform relevant operations on Form2 finally call 
 mainform.updateText(data);
```

Thats it . The change gets reflected in a textbox defined in the MainWindow.